# Using .Net SqlClient to connect to SQL Azure DB doesn't return any data

Tags: c#, azure, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database, sqlclient

I'm tryting to use .Net SqlClient to connect to SQL Azure DB and execute a stored procedure:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SqlConnection sqlDbConnection = new SqlConnection("Connectionstring");
            sqlDbConnection.Open();
            SqlCommand ewayPaymentCmd = new SqlCommand();
            SqlDataReader ewayPaymentReader;
            Guid eWayPaymentId = new Guid("9EACEB8C-87FD-4504-BC87-CA82C2A0F435");

            ewayPaymentCmd.Connection = sqlDbConnection;
            ewayPaymentCmd.CommandText = "spEWay_GetPayment";
            ewayPaymentCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            ewayPaymentCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eWayPaymentId", eWayPaymentId.ToString());

            ewayPaymentReader = ewayPaymentCmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (!ewayPaymentReader.HasRows)
            {
                throw new Exception("Unable to find eWay Payment Id");
            }

            ewayPaymentReader.Read();
        }
```

Somehow the ewayPaymentReader will not have any data (depth = 0) after stored procedure was executed, causing HasRows will always be false.

Checking the Db connection string i'm 100% that i'm connecting to the right database.

This is the stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spEWay_GetPayment]
    @eWayPaymentId UniqueIdentifier
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT *
    FROM EwayPayment
    WHERE eWayPaymentId = @eWayPaymentId
    AND ProcessedDateUTC IS NULL
END
```

Comment: Can you read the data? I mean does other function which only reads data works fine?

Comment: Are you still experiencing issues? Have you been able to reproduce the issue when using SSMS or a similar tool?